# Stylecop still checks generated file even I have the setting to skip it

Tags: visual-studio-2013, stylecop

I have a class library project with stylecop enabled, the rules skip all generated files like I have shown in screenshot here.

[image]

But when I start to add a new workflow activity (Activity1.xaml) I got error messages from Stylecop

- Warning as Error: Missing XML comment for publicly visible type or member 'MyProject.Activity1.Activity1()' C:\MyProject\Trunk\MyProject\obj\Debug\Activity1.g.cs
- Missing XML comment for publicly visible type or member 'MyProject.Activity1' C:\MyProject\Trunk\MyProject\obj\Debug\Activity1.g.cs

Can somebody explain to me how it happened?

Answer (score 0):

My humble opinion would be that StyleCop is probably just buggy, letting alone being not user-friendly (both are subjective).

See source code below, especially `SkipAnalysisForDocument` method:
https://stylecop.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Project/Src/AddIns/CSharp/Parser/CsParser.cs

It contains some spagetty mix of ".Designer.cs" hardcode and regex magic, with some not very clear logic above that. Maybe instead of `return Utils.InputMatchesRegExPattern(sourceCode.Path, filters)` it should say `return !Utils.InputMatchesRegExPattern(sourceCode.Path, filters)`, but it is hard to say without debugging.

Since the whole project looks abandoned - it does not seem that community would have a desire to fix anything. As for me personally, I never liked StyleCop source code and wondered how it could even work well with an overall code quality like that (subjective again).